# Check if string ends with more than one dot regex JS

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I use this pattern `/\.\.+$/g` to check whether a string ends with more than one dot. However it did not work. I don't know where my code went wrong, please help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
let text = "...Is this .. all there is..?";
//check if string end with more than one dot
let pat = /\.\.+$/g
let result = pat.test(text)
//should return true
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `?` is not a dot...

Comment: Your sentence doesn't end with any `.`s, it ends with a `?`. Hence your regex doesn't match.

Comment: Sidenote: You can drop the `+` from your regex if you just `test()` for more than one dot.

Comment: Since checking for 2 dots is enough, `text.endsWith('..')` should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\.{2,}` to detect 2 or more dots. Also you should add `[?!]?` if you plan using question or exclamation marks:

```js
let text = "...Is this .. all there is..?";

console.log(/\.{2,}[?!]?$/.test(text));
```

If you want detect both dots and marks:

```js
let text = "...Is this .. all there is..?";

console.log(/[.?!]{2,}$/.test(text));
```